# How to use tf.reduce_mean

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hey everyone I am new to tensorflow and I use a simple function

`from tensorflow.keras import layers, models import tensorflow as tf`

`inp = layers.Input(shape=10); loss_mean = tf.reduce_mean(inp); model=models.Model(inp, loss_mean); model.predict(np.random.randn(3, 10))`

And get the same error: Attempted to aggregate unsupported object -0.18395748734474182.

What am I doing wrong?
I use python3.6 tensorflow 1.15

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to an unsupported `Numpy` version installed in your system which is incompatible with `TensorFlow 1.15`.

You need to install `Numpy 1.17` to fix this error.

```
!pip install numpy==1.17
```

and run your existing code:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models 
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)

inp = layers.Input(shape=10); 
loss_mean = tf.reduce_mean(inp); 
model=models.Model(inp, loss_mean); 
model.predict(np.random.randn(3, 10))
```

Output:

```
2.8.2
1.17.0
-0.28963395953178406
```

Please refer to the link to have more details on [tf.reduce_mean()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_mean).

Comment: It is working because you use tensorflow version 2.8.2. When I used tensorflow 1.15 with numpy 1.17 I got the same error, but with tensorflow 2.8.2  I didn't